# Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive Closure verification or explanation

Tags: logic, relations

I've been given the following function where: 
$$R:0..10 \iff 0..10 $$
$$ R = \{ m,n\colon\mathbb{N} \| m \neq n \land m + n = 8 \} $$
Therefore, I've calculated R as:
$$ R = \{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0)\} $$
Reflexive Closure:
$$\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)\} $$

Symmetric Closure:
$$ \{(8,0),(7,1),(6,2),(5,3),(3,5),(2,6),(1,7),(0,8)\} $$
Transitive Closure:
$$ \{(3,3)\} $$
Are these correct?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything to add for transitive closure, your pair $(3,3)$ is already contained in the reflexive closure. Furthermore, your symmetric closure should already be contained in $R$ itself, as you don't have the condition that $m \leq n$. And last but not least, explanations and proofs are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Could you clarify what explanation and proof would be required?  Only that all the examples I've seen are the same format as I've provided above, if you could link to an appropriate example perhaps?

Comment: Reflexive Closure:
$$R \cup
\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)\}$$
Symmetric Closure:
$$\{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0)\}$$
Transitive Closure:
$$R \cup \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)\} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the reflexive closure, you have to add the points $(n,n)$ not only for $n$ in the field of your relation, but for $n$ in the set over which you are viewing your relation. Since the context here seems to be relations on the natural numbers between $0$ and $10$, according to what you wrote at first, then I would say that the reflexive closure of $R$ has all the elements of $R$ plus the pairs $(n,n)$ for $n\in\{0,1,\ldots,10\}$. So you need also to add $(4,4)$ and $(9,9)$ and $(10,10)$.

For the symmetric closure, what you wrote is fine, but actually it is the same as $R$ itself, since $R$ is already symmetric! So the symmetric closure of $R$ is $R$ itself.

For the transitive closure, you will end up adding the points that you've listed wrongly under the reflexive closure, since from $(0,8)$ and $(8,0)$ you've got to add $(0,0)$. From $(8,0)$ and $(0,8)$, you got to add $(8,8)$, and so on with the other numbers in the field.

Lastly, I thought you might like to see the figure I created illustrating the various kinds of closures of an example relation (not the same as your example). Some of my students found it useful to notice the differences in the various kinds of closures, and to discover the reason each diagram was as it was. I believe that anyone who can understand this picture really knows the reflexive, transitive and symmetric closures of a relation and their combinations.

[image]

I made a small post at https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JoelDavidHamkins1/posts/Gu3eScwxDzf.

Comment: Thank you for this, I wish I could up vote it x1000.

Comment: One question after I've thought about it more, is R not already Symmetric as every instance of (x,y) has an instance of (y,x)?  In my original post, I reversed R which may have confused things.

Comment: Yes, that is right! I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Reflexive Closure:
$$R \cup
\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)\}$$
Symmetric Closure:
$$\{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0)\}$$
Transitive Closure:
$$R \cup \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)\} $$

In the Transitive Closure, I've not included (4,4), (9,9) or (10,10) as they are not elements of R.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, looks right.